# Mongodb: too many users are authenticated

Tags: mongodb, authentication, authorization

I try to authorize on my db and get some records, but i get this strange error:

[image]
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You have authorized too many users. One solution is quit the shell first and then try to authorize again:

```
mongo
```

You don't need authorize when you create an connection

```
use your_file_db
```

now you can use

```
db.auth("db_user","db_pass")
```

and now you can get your records.
Or you can directly authorize the super manager and you can also get the records in your database.

Answer (score 1):

As per following mongodb jira issue, only one authentication allowed per session
https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-40967

you can only use that user inside mongodb, which you used while connecting through mongo shell.

doing db.auth() for any other user will give error.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if [this ticket](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-37520) is related, because I still see this issue with MongoDB 4.0.9, but the way I fixed it was to not use `db.auth()` but exit the shell, then log in again:

```
mongo --ssl mongodb://myhost.io --authenticationDatabase admin -u adminUser -p
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `db.logout()` to logout the user and more importantly it has to be **done inside of the databases the current user (that you're logging out of) has access to.**

For example lets say you're currently inside the `admin` database. If you switch to a different database and then logout, then login with the new user this error will be shown.